# How to access on Vector components when we don't know in advance its dimension

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For a two dimension vector i use this snippet, but if i don't know in advance the number of dimension of vector, how can i adapt my code ?

```
var vect = Vectors.dense(0,0)
var rdd_vects = sc.parallelize(Array(vect,vect,...))

var sum = rdd_vects.reduce( case (x,y) => Vectors.dense(x(0)+y(0),x(1)+y(1))  )
```

Thank you for your advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the vectors are of same dimension:

```
val sum = rdd_vects.reduce{ (x, y) => 
    Vectors.dense((x.toArray, y.toArray).zipped.map(_+_))
}
```

Comment: It's more elegant that mine.  I just don't find the zipped function in scala and spark APIs, it is the same than the zip function for RDD or Array ? I found this one but i'm not sure [link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$Ops)

Answer (score 1):

I think i found my answer by myself. Vector can be created with Vector.dense(Array[Double]) thus i run a for loop inside my reducer.

```
            var sum = rdd_vect.reduce( (x,y) => {

               var tab_vect = Array(0.0).tail
               var x_size = x.size
                for( ind <- 0 to x_size-1) {
                   val component_x = x(ind)
                   val component_y = y(ind)
                   val component_f = component_x + component_y
                   tab_vect = tab_vect :+ component_f
            }
            Vectors.dense(tab_vect)
            })
```